# Named Scope Extensions - Calling Method Outside Do Block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, named-scope

I have the following named_scope in my User model:

```
  named_scope :all_stars, :joins => [:all_stars] do
    def overall
      self.find(:all, :conditions => ['recordable_type = ?', 'User'])
    end
  end
```

I want to do this:

```
  named_scope :all_stars, :joins => [:all_stars] do
    def overall
      overall_all_stars_condition
    end
  end

  def overall_all_stars_condition
    self.find(:all, :conditions => ['recordable_type = ?', 'User']) 
  end
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make the other thing into another named scope, you can then chain together the two scopes, which will get you what you want.

```
named_scope :all_stars, :joins => [:all_stars]
named_scope :overall, :conditions => ['recordable_type = ?', 'User']
```

Then you should be able to call it as such:

```
object.all_stars.overall.all
object.overall.all_stars.find(:all)
# etc
```

And also create a method that does the same thing:

```
def overall_all_stars_condition
  self.all_stars.overall.all
end
```